# Forwarding a kvoption DefaultOption to a StringOption

Tags: kvoptions

I want to use kvoptions for a package, with a string option, and I want unknown options to be used as values for that string option. Like this:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{kvo}[2020/10/20 v 0.01 playing with kvoptions]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=cdr,prefix=cdr@,setkeys=\kvsetkeys}

\DeclareStringOption{bla}
\AddToKeyvalOption*{bla}{
    \immediate\write16{Option bla set to #1 which is the same as \cdr@bla. ***}
}
\DeclareDefaultOption{
    \immediate\write16{Default option: \CurrentOption}
    \kvsetkeys{cdr}{bla=\CurrentOption}
    \immediate\write16{Now cdr@bla is \cdr@bla}
}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
```

So I would expect that `\usepackage[toto]{kvo}` would set `\cdr@bla` to `toto`. Testing it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[toto]{kvo}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write16{And now cdr@bla is \cdr@bla.}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

and the relevant lines from my output are like this:

```
Default option: toto
Option bla set to toto which is the same as toto. ***
Now cdr@bla is toto
And now cdr@bla is .
```

What is happening that loses the value of `\cdr@bla`? What would be the right way to achieve what I want, i.e. transfer a Default Option to the setting of a String Option?

I know that I can say `\xdef\cdr@bla{\CurrentOption}` and that works, but if setting option `bla` has side-effects that would mean repeating code, or calling the same macro from both places, which I would find less readable.

Comment: \write16 isn't a good debugging tool here, as it will expand all commands. If you add a \show\cdr@bla in your package you will see that the command contains only \CurrentOption and \CurrentOption changes later. I would do something like `\newcommand\mysetbla[1]{\kvsetkeys{cdr}{bla=#1}}
\DeclareDefaultOption{\expandafter\mysetbla\expandafter{\CurrentOption}}` (or use expl3 for a similar effect.)

Comment: Ahhh ! ok everything is much clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: What should happen if multiple undefined options get used?

Comment: Presumably the side-effects for each of them would be applied in the order that they appear in the list and the final value of `\cdr@bla` would be the last undefined option, at least that would be the least surprising outcome for the user. In my use case I don't really expect this to happen though.

Comment: As I said defining DefaultOption to do `\xdef\cdr@bla{\CurrentOption}` and putting the side effects after the `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` would work fine, I was just wondering if there was a more idiomatic way.

Comment: I'd opt for `\DeclareDefaultOption{\let\cdr@bla\CurrentOption}` in that case, no need to go through the key=value parser for this if it's just a string option and you don't really need the `\AddToKeyvalOption*` stuff.

Comment: That seems to be the easiest way, indeed. I wanted to forward the call because I foresee cases where there is non-trivial stuff to perform using `\AddToKeyvalOption*`, typically loading a `.clo` file which would need to be done before parsing the next options.